# elgamal based decryption mixnet

Tags: elgamal-encryption

Can anybody help me to understand elgamal based decryption mixnet? Pure elgamal can be used in mixnet (re-encryption mixnet) and its very easy, and I have implemented decryption mixnet using RSA also.

See for example, http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.897/spring04/L18.pdf

But I have failed to gather any idea on the implementation of elgamal based decryption mixnet. Please help...

Comment: Why should RSA be working better than ElGamal for you? They both should have the same properties and if you implement them as functions they should both work equally well. P.S.: I'm commenting here becauseI want to get rid of some of the old unanswered questions in our unanswered statistic.